# How to change jsonb object array value for entire table?

Tags: json, postgresql, sql-update, jsonb, postgresql-11

i have a table with a JSONB column called "columnsettings". The jsonb data looks like:.

```
[
    {
        "data": "id",
        "width": 25
    },
    {
        "data": "field_1",
        "width": 125
    },
    {
        "data": "field_3",
        "width": 183
    },
    {
        "data": "field_11",
        "width": 125
    }
]
```

I now want to run an update on all rows in the table and change the "data" attribute ='newvalue' where the data value ='field_1" for example: The expected result for all rows would  be:

```
[
    {
        "data": "id",
        "width": 25
    },
    {
        "data": "newvalue",
        "width": 125
    },
    {
        "data": "field_3",
        "width": 183
    },
    {
        "data": "field_11",
        "width": 125
    }
]
```

I can't seem to find the right syntax to update this specific array value in all rows of table.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you'd need something like: `UPDATE tbl SET json_obj = json_obj || json_build_object('data', '<some_value>');` Not sure how you're handling which data gets which value though. This would apply the same `<some_value>` to every record. The concatenation like this will clobber any pre-existing `"data":<value>` tuple in the json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `JSONB_SET()` function nested in `JSONB_AGG()` within an `UPDATE` Statement containing a conditional, after splitting the elements of the array through applying `JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS()` function such as

```
UPDATE tab
   SET columnsettings =
   (
    SELECT JSONB_AGG(CASE WHEN j ->> 'data' = 'field_1' THEN 
                               JSONB_SET(j, '{data}', '"newvalue"')
                          ELSE
                               j
                           END)    
      FROM JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(columnsettings) AS j
   )
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=02751912a34da4d24abd1d389d9206e7)</kbd>